# develop php using terminal tools npm

Tags: php, npm, development-environment, yarnpkg

i enjoy developing frontend applications using terminal tools on macOS, tools like `create-react-app` or angular-cli you can easily start a new project from terminal inside any directory in system, just type create-react-app PROJECT_NAME and kaboom u r up and running.

is there any tools for php that can do same to ease development of php API ?

current best i can do is using php builtin server

inside any folder

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

this will start a php server. one problem is htaccess wont work.

Comment: Take a look for "composer"

Comment: yp i use it for pachages, i'm talking about server